# DelayedTask throwing 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function call' in Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to use `Ext.util.DelayedTask` to make some timed functions go off. I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function call`. It's coming from line 126 of DelayedTask.js in the Sencha source code. [Click here to see the source.](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/DelayedTask.html#Ext-util-DelayedTask)

Here is the code I wrote which runs the tasks.

```
var appView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.meterreadings_main')[0];
var meterList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.mbList[alias="meterListObject"]')[0];

var taskOne = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', {
    scope: this,
    fn:function() {
        appView.pop();
    }
});

var taskTwo = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', {
    scope: this,
    fn:function() {
        meterList.select(meterStore.getCurrentRecordIndex());
    }
});

var taskThree = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', {
    scope: this,
    fn:function() {
        meterList.config.itemTapHandler(null,meterStore.getCurrentRecordIndex(), null,
            meterStore.getCurrentRecord(), null, null);
    }
});

appView.pop();
taskOne.delay(500);
taskTwo.delay(1500);
taskThree.delay(2500);
```

See anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the ST2 docs show that you can create a delayed task like how you are currently doing, you actually need to do it the following way:

```
var taskOne = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
    console.log('delayed task');
}, this);
```

Here are the parameters you can pass, you'll see I already included the scope above:

**Parameters**

```
fn : Function
The default function to call.

scope : Object
The default scope (The this reference) in which the function is called. If not specified, this will refer to the browser window.

args : Array
The default Array of arguments.
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This worked great! Thanks. The solution I can up with was extending `Ext.util.DelayedTask`, overriding the `delay` function, and changing line 126 so that it didn't try to call the container of `fn` and instead called `fn` itself. This method worked too but it's better that I don't have to extend the class now.